# Get the first record from the list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the product with the highest price from a list of products using LINQ

```
Product Name     Product Category        Product Price
Mobile           Electronics             $300
Fridge           Electronics             $2500
chair            Furniture               $25
Table            Furniture               $80
Shirt            Clothing                $15
Pant             Clothing                $35
```

The desired output is

Electronics      Fridge     2500

I tried using break in the foreach, as per below.

How can I achieve this without using break?

```
var highCost = from highPrice in listProduct
           orderby highPrice.ProductPrice descending
           select highPrice;

 foreach(var item in highCost) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}     {2}", item.ProductCategory, 
         item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice);
    break;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `item.ProductPrice.GetType()`? on the first iteration through the loop?

Comment: @mjwills it's decimal

Comment: Please replace `foreach(var item in highCost) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}     {2}", item.ProductCategory, 
         item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice);
    break;
}` with `var bob = highCost.FirstOrDefault(); if (bob != null) Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}     {2}", item.ProductCategory, 
         item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice);`

Comment: @mjwills - that did the trick. Thank you for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you have used `First` or `FirstOrDefault` some wrong way.

This should do the trick:

```
var item = listProduct.OrderByDescending(e => e.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}     {2}", item.ProductCategory, 
         item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice);
}
```

Or in query syntax, if you prefer:

```
var item = (from highPrice in listProduct
            orderby highPrice.ProductPrice descending
            select highPrice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it was the First or FirstOrDefault placement issue indeed. I corrected the code and it is working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a product class

```
class Product
{
    public int ID{set;get;}
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Category { set; get; }
    public string PriceDollar { set; get; }
}
```

Code used to fill the list with three record for you clear understanding such as

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.ID = 1;
        p1.Name = "Mobile";
        p1.Category = "Electronics";
        p1.PriceDollar = "200";
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.ID = 2;
        p2.Name = "Mobile";
        p2.Category = "Electronics";
        p2.PriceDollar = "400";
        Product p3 = new Product();
        p3.ID = 3;
        p3.Name = "Chair";
        p3.Category = "Furniture";
        p3.PriceDollar = "100";

        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
        list.Add(p3);
```

To Get the first record of your product list use following code as I got result 200 of price and displayed in MessageBox.

```
var query = from hightPrice in list select hightPrice.PriceDollar;
        var firstRecordPrice = query.First();
        MessageBox.Show(firstRecordPrice);
```

Following Code will be used to get max of price from your list of product that display me in result of 400

```
var maxPrice = list.Max(p=>p.PriceDollar);
        MessageBox.Show(maxPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little bit different approach that has better O(N) runtime:

```
var productWithMaxPrice = listProduct.Aggregate((max, product) => 
    max.ProductPrice >= product.ProductPrice ? max : product);
```

LINQ method OrderByDescending uses `Quicksort` algorithm that has worse O(N*logN) runtime.